# How to debug into Cordova.framework in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm having a problem where cordova is failing to start the camera app on iOS.  A simple case works fine, but in my app, not so much.

So I'd like to debug into the Cordova.framework to see what the problem is.

But I can't figure out how to do it.  I've built the Cordova project that's sitting next to the installed framework, and I've replaced my framework reference in my project to point at it.  That seems to be fine.  But I can't step in or set breakpoints.

With the cordova project, i"m building UniversalFramework and it looks like it's set to debug in the scheme config, even though it always builds to release (this seems to be in the script), I see --DDEBUG in the clang output, so I think it's debug.  I'm fairly new to xcode so I don't know if it's building a symbol file or how to verify it's a debug framework, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Cordova (2.0.0) has it like a seperate project and linked as static library.
Use that version, you can put breakpoints in the library code.

Comment: Dear Petrov, it would be nice if you could describe how cordova 2.0.0 can be used in xcode because I keep getting cdvviewcontroller.h not found and stuff... you are the first person i come across who gives an information that actually means something... thank you

Comment: You need to go to your poject settings and set the directory in which to look for the headers. http://hoishing.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/screen-shot-2011-08-20-at-5-21-32-pm.png

Comment: Hahahaha thanks man very clear :). I hate the enter to post too, kind of stupid policy indeed :)